How to migrate password from Grails 2.x to Grails 6.x?
I am upgrading Grails 2.x to Grails 6.x along with Spring security 3.x to latest 6.x. Existing user password in database is plain hash "c80444fa0e57e8f3414471bb92fe800373343fde9bddc510a1f7df38baf62720" without id like {bcrypt} etc. So how do we configure password encoder in applicataion.groovy file please (Like for BCrypt grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm='bcrypt')
Looks like the Grails 2.x uses SHA256 because the password is "System@123" and https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html tool gives above hash. But putting SHA256 in config file prefixes id like {SHA256} and different hash.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

I'm not really sure what the question/problem is here. You've identified that things have changed in Spring Security from 3.x to 6.x, so you already know that. So what is the problem you are facing? There is discussion with history at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/authentication/password-storage.html.

https://medium.com/swlh/password-migration-from-grails-2-to-grails-4-spring-security-3-to-spring-security-5-318e4e109210 this is helpful
